# Personalized web push notifications

Tags: web, push-notification

I want to send web push notifications to registered users, are there any best practices on how to implement the cases when multiple users have access to the same device and one should not see the message of another user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web push notification subscription is tied to the browser, not the device.

What you need to do is, map this id with your registered user when he logs in from a particular browser. Also, you need to remove the subscription id mapping with any other users in the system.

In the case of multiple users using the same browser, the above logic will make sure that at a time, a particular browser subscription id is linked only to a single user.

And when you want to send a notification to a registered user, you can retrieve all push subscription IDs linked to this user in your database, and trigger notifications to those subscription IDs.

And don't forget to unmap a subscription id when the user logs out from a browser. Otherwise, he will continue to receive all notifications even if he has logged out.